# Moving MS office file from multi directories to one directory

Tags: 64-bit

I have all Ms office, Doc, xls, ppt, file scatter all over in different directories on my external hardrive
I would like to move them to one director all
*.doc & *.docx in a word directory with a sub directory where the come from
*.xls & *.xlsx in a excel directory with a sub directory where the come from
same with all the other types of MS office documents

In c:\ I create a directory c:\msdoc\
Under the msdoc  instead of manually create a sub-directory the batch file create automatically the sub directory  where the files come from

say I have file in c:\afiles\minopex
then the batch file should create under c:\msdoc\  the sub-directory minopox and move all the *.doc to the new location
the same for all other type of files

How can i write a batch file to do this

Answer (score 0):

you can
- use a for loop with /r for recursivly parsing a directory
- use %%f in collection (e.g. *.xls) to grab the files from the for loop
- use the move-command to move files to a specific directory.

so for doc files it would be a one liner, for xls you could use a second line and so on...

Comment: I am a bit green on the cmd input can you give me a example